# Issues converting columns to datetime column ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: unconverted data remains: 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
        CODE    STATION  year  month  day  TMAX  TMIN  PPTOT
0     472606FA  AYABACA  2001      1    1  18.0  10.1    0.0
1     472606FA  AYABACA  2001      1    2  18.7   9.6    0.0
2     472606FA  AYABACA  2001      1    3  19.6   9.3    0.7
3     472606FA  AYABACA  2001      1    4   NaN  10.4    NaN
4     472606FA  AYABACA  2001      1    5   NaN   NaN    NaN
       ...      ...   ...    ...  ...   ...   ...    ...
7420  4725F170   HUAROS  2021      4   26  15.6   5.2    0.0
7421  4725F170   HUAROS  2021      4   27  14.4   4.6    0.0
7422  4725F170   HUAROS  2021      4   28  12.9   4.0    0.0
7423  4725F170   HUAROS  2021      4   29  13.5   3.7    0.0
7424  4725F170   HUAROS  2021      4   30  13.0   4.1    0.0
```

I want to convert year month day columns to datetime so i wrote this code:

```
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']],format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I tried also without the format:

```
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])
```

But i get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: unconverted data remains: 2
```

I checked all the values and there is no nan values in year, month, day. Also there is no strange characters.

I don't know what can be the error.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with errors='coerce' parameter of `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']],errors='coerce')
```

**Note:**
It is working in pandas 1.2.4 so If It is not worked then try considering upgrading pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use .str.cat() to tie the entities together and then convert using pd.to_datetime. Code below

```
my_df['Date']=my_df[['year', 'month', 'day']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.astype(str).str.cat(sep='/'),format="%Y/%m/%d"), axis=1)




my_df.dtypes

CODE               object
STATION            object
year                int64
month               int64
day                 int64
TMAX              float64
TMIN              float64
PPTOT             float64
Date       datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.to_datetime`, with `join`

```
df[["year","month","day"]].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime('/'.join(x.values.astype(str))), axis=1)
```